# Why is the action for a field a quadruple integral over spacetime?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, classical-field-theory

I've been trying to get started on classical field theories. As I had been studying classical mechanics from Goldstein, I decided to start from there. 
Goldstein introduces the action $$S=\int \mathscr{L} d^4x$$ by doing the specific case of a system of coupled springs and then passing to the limit to make the degrees of freedom continuous. Then he takes this to be the general action for a field. 
 Susskind in his Theoretical Minimum book series instead makes an argument that while the ordinary action of a system is an integral over a length of time, because special relativity must be the natural setting of classical field theories, the natural generalization is an integral over a volume of spacetime. 
 I, however, am not satisfied. In comparison with the action principle for discrete systems, which has a clear reasoning trickling down from d'Alembert's principle, this seems more like a well-inspired guess, which makes me wonder if there isn't a better explanation? On one hand, I suppose that any system in which the forces can be derived from a potential, in equilibrium, can be well approximated by harmonic oscillators. But is that the right answer? What does it even mean for a system comprised of a field to have forces derived from a potential?
I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: Informal: The harmonic oscillator is just an example, and because the potential is linear in the coordinates, it's a good starting point for potential approximations. It is also a convenient analogy because when "expanding" fields into "modes", one does so with $e^{\pm ip\cdot x}$, which are "waves". Imposing "causality", one finds the canonical commutation relations (the same as the harmonic oscillator) in the expansion coefficients. Once fields get promoted to operators, these will turn out to be "creation-destruction" operators, which are again related to the H.O, yet in quantized fashion

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/550600/2451 and links therein.